# How to serve mixed static and dynamic ads from a database?

Tags: django, theory, ads, google-ads-api

I'm building an application in Django that needs to integrate advertising into the site. I need to serve ads based on "ad priority" as determined by tho following:

1. If the page "owner" has an ad that they have paid for in the system, serve that/those ad(s) first.
2. If not, serve Google AdWords ads or some other type of ads in their place.

I'm somewhat new to working with ads in a dynamic site like this one, so what should I do? Obviously, all of this should be backed by a database, but how should I model it? It seems like there will be 3 types of ads: image/hyperlink custom ads, flash custom ads, and Google AdWords ads. Is this pretty accurate? Do I need to worry about XSS (cross-site-scripting) if I do this?

If you were me, how would you go about doing this in Django? I know it's somewhat subjective, but I'm pretty much in the dark and would love to hear some good ideas. It would be nice to simply go exclusively with Google AdWords or a similar service, but serving custom paid ads is pivotal in the business model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with [Google Ad Manager](https://www.google.com/dfp/info/welcome.html). You can serve custom campaigns, and if there're none, you can set it up to show AdSense.

Comment: Thanks @Tiago. Looks like some really sweet software, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Django but I've done this not too long ago. I simply stored the HTML as one of the database columns. After some simple logic to decide which ad to place, I just put the ad HTML onto the page.

The logic to decide which ad to serve can get extremely complex. I tried a few different approaches and expect I'll need others to handle all advertising scenarios. But your requirements sound like they are pretty straight forward.

Comment: What about cross-site-scripting though? Giving someone a simple HTML form that they can edit could give anyone the power to inject something malicious like this: `<script type="text/javascript">alert.show("Haldo!");</script>` or worse. I know I should probably trust my advertisers, but even if it wasn't malicious they could dramatically retheme their page as is often the case on the ancient MySpace.

Comment: I was talking about HTML you'd store in the database. I assumed only the admins would be able to edit the ads displayed on your site. Keep in mind that a lot of advertisers will want to include javascript in their ad. They can do even more damage using JavaScript. Bottom line: If you don't trust these people, you probably won't want to let them control what appears on your site.

Comment: Yeah. Basically, the idea is that companies register with the site, and if they pay for it as an extra feature, they can run ads on their company pages. In short, I can't guarantee or be sure of what they're putting in there.

Comment: Well, the only other option is to have that enter plain text and then you HTML encode and convert it to HTML. But I doubt this will do because most ads will need to give them control (links, javascript, etc.) I don't see how you can possibly allow them to enter their own ads and not open yourself up to risk.